# PostgresSQL permission to alter a table owned by another user

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgresSQL, I want to set up an admin user role and let the admins modify tables.

Is it possible to allow a user to do operations like CREATE INDEX and ALTER TABLE for a table that is owned by another user? I don't seem to be able to find a way to do it looking through the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define the members of the `admin` role as `NOINHERIT` and give the `CREATE` privilege on schemas only to `admin`.

Then the members have to execute

```
SET ROLE admin;
```

before they can create objects, and every member of `admin` can `ALTER` and `DROP` such objects.